# Problem with Bohr Frequency in Quantized Radiation - Matter interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

Consider an Hydrogenic Atom (no relativistic corrections and no reduced-mass effects) in a Quantized Electromagnetic Pulse given by the wave-packet:
$$
\underline{\hat{A}}(\underline{\hat{r}}, t) = \int_{[w_0 - \Delta w/2, w_0 + \Delta w/2]} \mathop{dw} \frac{\hbar}{2 \epsilon_0 V w} \underline{\epsilon} e^{i \delta_w}[\hat a_w e^{i(\underline k \cdot \underline{\hat{r}} - wt)} + \hat a_w^\dagger e^{-i(\underline k \cdot \underline{\hat{r}} - wt)}]
$$
where we assume incoherence ($<e^{i\delta_w}e^{i\delta_{w'}}> = \delta(w-w')$).

The Total Hamiltonian is thus:
$$
\hat H = \hat H_{atom} + \hat H_{field} + \hat H_{interaction}
$$
where the last term may be treated as a time-dependent perturbation in the weak field approximation:
$$
\hat H_{interaction} = -\frac{e}{m} \underline{\hat{A}} \cdot \underline{\hat{p}}
$$
where we have chosen the Radiation Gauge to make this result possible (in particular we needed $[\underline{\hat{A}}, \underline{\hat{p}}] = 0$).

Now, I have applied the Time-Dependent Perturbation Theory as in the semi-classical treatment (see "Physics of Atoms & Molecules" by Brandsen and Joachain) however a problem arises when computing the Bohr Frequency because in this case I have to consider the energy variation of both the atom **and the field** so that, when I do all the computations, I end up having a $\delta(w-0)$ in the integral for the transition probability (insted of $\delta(w-w_{ba})$ where $w_{ba}$ contains only the energy variation of the atom).

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong and what I should actually be doing? Is my procedure at all correct? It seems to me that it should be so because it is the same adopted in many lecture notes on the internet, however in those notes they always consider just the energy variation of the atom when defining the Bohr Frequency (which is not consistent with Dirac's Time-Dependent Perturbation Theory given the form of $\hat H$).